# How to save any file with date-time stamp quickly ?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Many time we open notepad, MS paint, MS word, MS Excel and other application and want to save file quickly with just date time stamp in save as dialog box. Is there any way to save files with date time stamp ?

Comment: no, without a 3rd party solution

Comment: Similar question here, though answer is not accepted; http://superuser.com/questions/1079789/how-to-save-any-file-with-date-time-stamp-quickly